# Is it possible to find out when a change was originally committed after its branch was rebased?

Tags: git

I have two branches, `master` and `feature`. I'm working and committing to `feature`, while others are merging to `master`. I'm rebasing `feature` onto `master` daily to avoid potentially horrendous conflicts in the future when I go to merge into `master`. What I'm curious about, is whether it's possible for me to see when each of my commits was originally made (on `feature`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git log` by default shows Author Date, which *is* the time when the commit was originally made.  Commit Date is the one that changes when you rebase.

Answer (score 1):

You can say

```
git show --format=fuller <mycommitSHA>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you rebase changes of master to feature branch (git rebase master) the commit history is rewritten. However, if you create a temp branch before rebasing then that branch will keep the history.

For ex:
git checkout feature

git checkout -b tempfeature

git checkout feature

git rebase master

git checkout tempfeature

git log --oneline

tempfeature branch should keep your previous history